# How to position multiple images or tikzpictures in beamer background

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, positioning, backgrounds, includegraphics

I’d like to rebuild a PowerPoint template with beamer. For this, I need to position several graphic elements in the background of a frame. I have tried so many ways and codes but have several problems. Please consider this MWE, for example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

{\usebackgroundtemplate{
\begin{picture}(0,0)
\put(0,-50){
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
\node [anchor=south west] (rect) at (0,0) [fill=blue, minimum width=16.0cm,minimum height=0.5cm] {};
\node [anchor=south west] (rect) at (0,0.5) [fill=black, minimum width=16cm, minimum height=2cm] {};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{picture}

\begin{picture}(0,0)
\put(0,-225){
\includegraphics[width=3cm]{pictures/image1.png}
\end{picture}

\begin{picture}(0,0)
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
\node[anchor=south west, inner sep=0pt] (image2) at (current page.south west){\includegraphics[width=8cm]{pictures/image2.png}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{picture}
}
\begin{frame}
Test
\end{frame}

}

\end{document}
```

Commenting the second picture at least gives an output. Besides this problem, I am struggling with the following thing: How can I force beamer to place the figures at left side of the frame without any margins. Working with negative values for \put works but is not a good solution and has to be done separately for every graphical element.

Why is image2 not even showing up? I thought working with a node at the south west corner of the page would be a clever idea.

Adding stuff makes the elements change their postion – for example some text above of image 1. How can a force element to just stay where I have placed them?

Comment: add `}` after `\includegraphics[width=3cm]{pictures/image1.png}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\usebackgroundtemplate{

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay] % <----------
\node [anchor=north west] (black rect) at (current page.north west) 
        [fill=black, minimum width=16cm, minimum height=2cm] {};

\node [anchor=north] at (black rect.south) 
     [fill=blue, minimum width=16.0cm,minimum height=0.5cm] {};

\node[anchor=south west, inner sep=0pt] (image2) at (current page.south west)
     {\includegraphics[width=8cm]{pictures/image2.png}};

\node[anchor=south east, inner sep=0pt] at (current page.south east)
     {\includegraphics[width=3cm]{pictures/image1.png}};
\end{tikzpicture}
}



\begin{frame}
Test
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Comment: I used to wrap the frames in the \usebackgroundtemplate. That was one of the mistakes